# Knockout js foreach grid not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7RDc3/2096/

The 'Add Service' button doesn't work. I need it to mirror the functionality of the 'Add Hardware' button.
Something is wrong with my code below: You can see it in action on the fiddle above though.

```
var viewModel = function(hardware, services) {
    var self = this;
    self.hardwares = ko.observableArray(hardware);
    self.services = ko.observableArray(services);

    self.addHardware = function() {
        self.hardwares.push({
            name: "",
            price: ""
        });
    };

    self.removeHardware = function(hardware) {
        self.hardwares.remove(hardware);
    };

     self.addService = function() {
        self.services.push({
            name: "",
            price: ""
        });
    };

    self.removeService = function(services) {
        self.services.remove(services);
    };
    self.save = function(form) {
        var allModel = [];
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(services(), function (service) {
                allOrders.push(ko.toJS(service));
            });
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(hardwares(), function (hardware) {
                allOrders.push(ko.toJS(hardware));
            });
            alert("Could now transmit to server: " + ko.utils.stringifyJson(allOrders));
    };
};

var FinalViewModel = new viewModel([]);
ko.applyBindings(FinalViewModel);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not passing an argument in for the `services` parameter when you construct the viewmodel:

```
var FinalViewModel = new viewModel([], []); 
ko.applyBindings(FinalViewModel);
```

**Updated fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7RDc3/2097/

You could also augment your constructor to use empty arrays if an argument isn't supplied:

```
var viewModel = function(hardware, services) {
    var self = this;
    self.hardwares = ko.observableArray(hardware || []);
    self.services = ko.observableArray(services || []);
    /* snip */
};
```

Comment: Perfect!!! One more thing, the alert isn't popping up on submit, could you take a look? http://jsfiddle.net/7RDc3/2098/

Comment: @StephenHarman: A few things there: 1. You need `click` binding on the submit button (or alternatively a submit event binding on the form itself), and 2. You need to iterate over `self.services()` and `self.hardwares()`: http://jsfiddle.net/7RDc3/2099/

Comment: Works great! Thank you! Just noticed that in the JSON the name select is sending the name of it rather than the value, have any idea?

Comment: @StephenHarman As for the checkboxes, use the `checked` binding instead: http://jsfiddle.net/7RDc3/2100/. For the `select`, the option doesn't have a value so it's not being set (set a `value="1"` on the option and you should see it populated)

Comment: Perfect! Works as intended. I had just submitted the checkbox thing and realized I read that in the API. And I don't know how I missed the value thing. Anyways, thank you.